# Access to Javafx elements from another class without FXML

Tags: java, javafx, eventhandler

I am using Javafx8 and lets say i have created many ui items (like buttons and so on...). I thought its a good idea to put all EventHandler for these buttons into a separates class. My question is: How can i get access from an EventHandler to any button, e.g. to diable it or to manipulate it on any other way.

Here is a minimum example with two buttons and a separate class for EventHandlers

Let's say this is my Start class:

```
public class App extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Button b1 = new Button();
        b1.setOnAction(ListenerClass.createB1Event());
        Button b2 = new Button();
        b2.setOnAction(ListenerClass.createB2Event());

        VBox vbox = new VBox(b1, b2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 200, 200);

        primaryStage.setTitle("App");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

And my (separate) listener class:

```
public class ListenerClass {

    public static EventHandler<ActionEvent> createB1Event() {
        return new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                //Access here to b1 and b2...
                //Deactivate B1
                //Activate B2
            }
        };
    }

    public static EventHandler<ActionEvent> createB2Event() {
        return new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                //Access here to b1 and b2...
                //Activate B1
                //Dectivate B2
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid you thought wrong; that is a horrible idea. As your application grows in complexity, this will be a nightmare to maintain. The EventHandlers should be kept in the same class that controls their scene...

Comment: On an unrelated note, you may consider using either `RadioButton` or `ToggleButton` for your case, since you essentially want to toggle between the two options and only allow one to be selected at a time.

Comment: I don´t fully agree with that statement since it´s kinda the idea of MVC that you put the events into the controller and the view into the (in javafx case fxml file). That seperation does not always work too well, because some things fxml just plain does not support.
Basically, I don´t believe he had an inherently bad idea. It just wasn´t executed well.

Comment: I just created a simple stupid example with two buttons. In reality its an app with > 30 buttons and alle other stuff. This means, that i had all Eventhandler-implementations in the same class. This class grew up like hell. Thats why i thought to create a separate class. But then i had the problem to access these objects. I could ask differently: What would be the "best practise" for those cases: Using a strict MVC pattern or put all eventhandlers in one class?

Answer (score 1):

So based on your principal. You want the button that is located in a vbox and got pressed to be disabled and all other buttons from that vbox to be enabled.
And your problem is how to find button that got pressed.

You need to use ActionEvent.getSource() method.

Heres how I'd code it....

This is Start class:

```
public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    Button b1 = addNewButton("Button1",vbox);
    Button b2 = addNewButton("Button2",vbox);
    Button b3 = addNewButton("Button3",vbox);


    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 200, 200);

    primaryStage.setTitle("App");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static Button addNewButton(String label, VBox ownerVBox){
    Button button = new Button(label);
    ownerVBox.getChildren().add(button);
    button.setOnAction(ListenerClass.createBEvent());
    return button;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Listener class:

```
public class ListenerClass {

public static EventHandler<ActionEvent> createBEvent() {
    return new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            Button b = (Button) t.getSource();
            VBox vbox =(VBox) b.getParent();
            vbox.getChildren().forEach(button-> {
                button.setDisable(false);
            });
            b.setDisable(true);
        }
    };
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i could be so easy. I will adapt it for my purposes.

Comment: Btw, i have a next question: How can i get access to these buttons using an EventHandler for a MenuItem? The parent should be MenuItem menuitem = (MenuItem) t.getSource();  Menu m = (Menu) menuitem.getParentMenu(); How can i get the "root" of this ui-component-tree?